# Dynamic Image List from MUI do not respect max height of the React container

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, grid

I am trying to create a dynamic image list where I can change the number of images that are being displayed, where the images have to occupy the max space in the component without change the image ratio and also without make the component scrollable. The following images show the result that is expected:
[image: Figure 1. Correct behaviour with 2 images]

[image: Figure 2. Correct behaviour with 6 images]

Although what really happens now is, in the first case, with only 2 images, it overflows the parent component due to the spacing added between the flexbox elements.
[image: Figure 3. Wrong behaviour with 2 images]

For the 6 images example, it goes worst: [image: Figure 4. Correct behaviour with 6 images]
It overflows the parent even more because it ignores the component's max height and always tries to occupy the max width possible.

To reach the correct behaviour, I'm hard coding the flex-basis of the image list for each case because it is a flex item, and only that way does it not grow more than it should. Although, that is not desirable because I want to make the images grow as much as possible without depending on the screen size.
I do not understand why they ignore the parent's max height.

I do not understand why they do ignore the max height of the parent.

Main component:

```
<>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        wrap="nowrap"
        rowSpacing={1}
        sx={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', margin: 0, height: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
      >
        <Grid
          container
          wrap="nowrap"
          item
          sx={{
            alignSelf: 'flex-start',
            flex: '1 0 auto',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <CustomImageList ref={ref}  />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <CustomPagination onClick={keyMap.move} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid width="100%" item>
          <Stack
            spacing={1}
            direction="row"
            sx={{
              overflowX: 'auto',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              '& .MuiFormControl-root': { marginTop: '1px' },
            }}
            divider={<Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />}
          >
            {Buttons.map((button) => (
              <Stack spacing={1} flex={1} key={button.buttonId}>
                <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
                  {button.text ? (
                    <ButtonText button={button} />
                  ) : (
                    <Button />
                  )}
                </Stack>
                <Stack spacing={1} direction="row">
                  <ButtonBox button={button} />
                </Stack>
              </Stack>
            ))}
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
     
    </>
```

The component `CustomImageList` is sketch like the next code:

```
<>
          <Stack justifyContent="center">
            <IconButton
              ref={leftArrowRef}
              size="large"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                handleClick({
                  key: 'ArrowLeft',
                  keyCode: 37,
                });
              }}
            >
              <ArrowBackIosNewIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Stack>
          <ImageList
            sx={{
              height: '100%',
              alignContent: 'center'
        
            }}
            cols={imageColumnCount}
          >
            {images.map((image, index) =>
               createOrdinaryListItem(image, index)
            )}
          </ImageList>

          <Stack justifyContent="center">
            <IconButton
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                handleClick({
                  key: 'ArrowRight',
                  keyCode: 39,
                });
              }}
              ref={rightArrowRef}
              size="large"
            >
              <ArrowForwardIosIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Stack>
        </>
```

The `ImageList` component is a [MUI ImageList](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-image-list/#main-content)

What would be the best approach to create the scenario shown in the first and second figures?   I have already tried to create my component. It was a flexbox where I used the breakpoint from the grid to distribute the columns across the images. I had the same behaviour that I presented here.

Sorry about the verbose post and kinda "hard to understand" question, but I was not capable of creating a runnable script to show what is aforementioned

Comment: Nope. I had to change the way I was rendering the images.

Comment: Me too. For anyone else running into this problem I ended up using the `background-url` method with divs. But you could use the CardMedia component which does the same thing. ImageList just seems to be an after-thought of a component tbh.